# Matlab: Use previous matrices from "for" loop to create new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've written the code below to determine the probability of colors occurring inside the COLUMNS of matrix X.
Index numbers 0-7 refer to these colors.

The problem I have is - I want to have "probability of colour 0" in row 1, then "probability of color 1" in row 2 and so on, in a new matrix. I've searched far and wide on Google and help docs, but still have no idea.

```
[rows, cols] = size(X);

for index = 0:7   
    B = (X == index);
    colour_in_columns = sum(B,1);
    prob_colour_in_columns = (colour_in_columns ./rows);
    index = index + 1;

end
```

Comment: can you post sample `X`? Will you get desired result if same calculation is done on `transpose(X)`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically(and I hope this works) you add each prob_colour_in_columns to itself

```
newmatrix=[newmatrix;prob_colour_in_columns];
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying "by hand" your `index` variable inside the `for` loop doesn't work the way you think. Each time loop body is executed again, Matlab will overwrite your `index` with whatever is the next value in the list 0:7 you gave. It may be that the last line in the loop's body is a mistake, and you might want to remove it.

Comment: @Parag: You're right, I'm sorry about that. I'll keep it in mind for my future answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the probability of colors occurring inside the rows of matrix X in a similar way: Suppose

```
X=[1 2 3 4;
   5 1 1 0;
   7 7 7 7;
   0 7 6 6]

[rows, cols] = size(X);

for index = 0:7   
    B = (X == index);
    colour_in_rows = sum(B,2);
    prob_colour_in_rows = (colour_in_columns ./cols);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply with a one-liner:

```
% Suppose your matrix is 3x3
X = randi([0,7],3);

out = histc(X,0:7,2)./size(X,2)
```

In `out(1,:)` you will have the probabilities of colour 0 to 7 happening in row 1 of X. 
In `out(2,:)` you will have the probabilities of colour 0 to 7 happening in row 2 of X and so forth...